# Under VPN connection can ping by dns name, but cannot cannot resolve in browser

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn

While I working under VPN, 
I can ping the server and it resolves the IP address

```
ping someserver.com
```

If I put someserver.com in browser, it says "cannnot establish connection".
I tried the same scenario on different environment - everything works fine.
What can be wrong with my environment? Could be something wrong with DNS names? For VPN I use PulseSecure

Some output

```
 cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search consumer.org crinfra.net consumerreports.org
nameserver 10.22.2.14
nameserver 10.22.2.13

 cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

nslookup jira.consumer.org
Server:     10.22.2.14
Address:    10.22.2.14#53

jira.consumer.org   canonical name = 2oqes.x.incapdns.net.
Name:   2oqes.x.incapdns.net
Address: 199.83.128.65
```

Comment: `ping` uses `ICMP ECHO_REQUEST` to check basic connectivity. Your browser uses `TCP:80` and depends on a working server at `someserver.com`

Comment: but it works from  another machine, but on machine it's not

Comment: Depending on how your browser works, and how your environment is set up, the browser may simply not be honoring the new DNS provided by the VPN, or not even using the VPN at all. There isn't enough information here to effectively answer the question. Consider adding the output of 
`cat /etc/resolv.conf ` and 
`/etc/nsswitch.conf` to your question and seeing if your browser can access any other resources, particularly ones on your local network.

Comment: possibly useful: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1736206-pulse-secure-vpn-dns-not-resolving

Comment: Also consider attaching the output of `nslookup someserver.com` or `dig someserver.com`, whichever works on your system.